# Jhipster - installing AWS module

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, jhipster

I have a project created with Jhipster which is hosted in AWS. Things were working pretty well, but I had to format my computer and reinstall everything (same OS - Ubuntu 15.10). Then, I've installed nodejs 5.10.0, npm 3.8.3 and Jhipster 3.0. In order to install Jhipster, I followed the steps described [here](http://jhipster.github.io/installation/), but using `sudo` to install the packages:

```
sudo npm install -g yo
sudo npm install -g bower
sudo npm install -g grunt
sudo npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

*(My project was originally built upon Jhipster 2.23 and uses grunt instead of gulp).*

Then, I followed the steps described [here](http://jhipster.github.io/aws/) to install the aws generator (once more, using `sudo`): `$sudo npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid`

In my system, instead of installed at `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, the global node modules can be found at `/usr/lib/node_modules`.

But when I run the command to install those modules, I get an error message and the `generator-jhipster` folder is deleted(!)

```
$cd /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster
$sudo npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid
generator-jhipster@2.23.1 /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster
├── aws-sdk@2.3.0  extraneous
├── node-uuid@1.4.7  extraneous
└── progress@1.1.8  extraneous

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "aws-sdk" "progress" "node-uuid"
npm ERR! node v5.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-ad396f5f
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-ad396f5f' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-ad396f5f' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "aws-sdk" "progress" "node-uuid"
npm ERR! node v5.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.2689400133
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.2689400133'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.2689400133'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/npm-debug.log
```

I remember when I installed it in my previous environment, I also had issues installing the aws module, but I was able to made it work by using some sort of trick. I couldn't come up with anything this time.

I also tried installing the same jhipster version I had in the past (2.23), tried changing the permissions to the node_manager folder and running everything without `sudo`, tried installing it in my home folder but nothing worked. Whenever I run `npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid` under the `generator-jhipster` folder, the previous error is raised and that folder is deleted.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Following @gaël-marziou's hint, I've reinstalled node using nvm. I've installed node v4.4.2, which is a LTS version. Now everything is installed under `~/.nvm` folder. When I try to install amy package under `generator-jhipster` folder, I got the same issue:

```
~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster$ npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid
generator-jhipster@2.23.1 /home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster
├── aws-sdk@2.3.0  extraneous
├── node-uuid@1.4.7  extraneous
└── progress@1.1.8  extraneous

npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/node" "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/npm" "install" "aws-sdk" "progress" "node-uuid"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.5
npm ERR! path /home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-b76490c0
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-b76490c0' -> '/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/.staging/generator-jhipster-b76490c0' -> '/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! Linux 4.2.0-34-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/node" "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/npm" "install" "aws-sdk" "progress" "node-uuid"
npm ERR! node v4.4.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.5
npm ERR! path npm-debug.log.151200600
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.151200600'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'npm-debug.log.151200600'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/npm-debug.log
```

Thanks,
Jodevan.

Answer (score 1):

Few comments:

- You should not run npm using sudo (see https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)
- You should use an LTS version of Node as we recommend it in doc.
- Also as you're on Ubuntu, I recommend to use nvm to install node, this way you can have several versions.

**More important**: JHipster does not support project upgrades from 2.x to 3.0.

You should install the same version you used: `npm install -g generator-jhipster@2.23.1`

Comment: 1. Strange. As far as I remember, I installed it in the same way I did it previously. I installed using these steps: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#debinstall.
2. **Which node version do you recommend?** I tried both 4.x and 5.x.
3. I'll give nvm a try.

BTW, I'm not upgrading Jhipster. Since I had to format my computer, I ended up installing version 3.0 but I downgraded it to 2.23. All I want is just to use the aws module to deploy my project to AWS.

Thanks!

Comment: Just made the suggested changes. Still no luck. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: OK I corrected for sudo node and gave a link for sudo npm. We use latest LTS. 4.4.x. This does not look like a jhipster issue but rather an environement issue, you don't use nvm but I can see this in your trace: npm ERR! argv "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/node" "/home/jodevan/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.2/bin/npm" "install" "aws-sdk" "progress" "node-uuid"

Comment: Last idea before I give up: are you sure that the aws-sdk version you installed is the same one as what is expected by jh 2.23? You could also try our devbox in 2.26 which is the oldest version we have for it: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox/tree/v2.26.0

Comment: No, unfortunately, I am not. I didn't have the chance to check the version I had installed before reinstalling everything. However, I tried to install each module separately (only `aws-sdk` and later only `progress`) and the same error occurred and the `generator-jhipster` ended up being deleted as well. But the 2.26 devbox is a great idea! I'll take a look at it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I ended up having to reinstall my system once more and this time everything worked just fine. I've installed `node` v.4.4.4 (LTS) using the ppa repository found at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager (I had done that in my previous attempt, too). I've also installed JHipster (2.23) and its dependencies using the instructions found at http://jhipster.github.io/installation and even the same instructions listed at http://jhipster.github.io/aws.

Now everything works perfectly. Go figure...

Comment: Just figured out what happened: When I installed node, the npm version was 2.x. Running `npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid` does work with this version. What happened in my previous attempt was that I had upgraded npm (npm install npm), the my npm version became 3.9.5. Running `npm install aws-sdk progress node-uuid` doesn't get along well with this npm version and this how all my problems started.